# Geoserver extremely slow performance on Raspberry pi model 3b

Tags: postgis, geoserver, performance, raspberry-pi

I have a postGIS database and tomcat8 with Geoserver installed in my raspberry pi model 3b running Ubuntu MATE.

The problem is, geoserver runs really slow, and I mean **really** slow. It takes up to 15 minutes to load just the presentation view in 127.0.0.1/geoserver.

This is not really an inconvenient anyway, since it's already configured (took forever), but since this is a service I have to use online for a map-based application, it's certainly not good.

We (my team) are working with leaflet, angular and spring, complementary to postgres and the geoserver for the layers. It takes literally 5 to 10 minutes to load the map every time a user moves through it or just zooms in/out.

I have no idea why, connection is good 100mbps up/down, the rest of the tomcat apps are running allright, it doesn't even have any load, it's 2 users at the same time max.

Comment: Can you run `top` or `htop` on it and see if its CPU-bound or out of real RAM? How much RAM does it have? What's the disk arrangement? I had a very slow Pi backup server that sped up x100 when I mounted the external USB with `noatime' options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're trying to ask too much out of that hardware... running a GeoServer requires a "server" (a laptop PC will do, even a few years old), the Raspberry does not have enough computational power.

I believe that running a full fledged distro like Ubuntu MATE is not helping, but the real issue is the hardware.

Comment: Yeah, apparently, lol. I've run it before in virtual machines and thought it wouldn't require much, guess I was wrong, CPU goes up to 150% when loading geoserver.

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read also this thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/help-Geoserver-raspberry-pi-CPU-tc5305841.html#a5305867

Answer (score 1):

I've had not unreasonable results with my RaspberryPi 3, though I'm not trying to do any complex rendering yet. You can see a lag when panning or scrolling a map but using tiles and caching helps with that (as you'd expect).

I wouldn't want to use it as a server for production but as a test platform and for taking out in the field with no power it's fine. Also I'm not running the client on it which probably helps - splash out and get a second Pi for that.

I'm running tomcat on Raspbian using

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Xmx756M -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=36000 -XX:+UseParallelGC --XX:+UseParNewGC "
```